# MySql table - display jsp only shows first row

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am trying to display all the records from a MySql Database into a JSP page.
I have the following code but it only display the first row. How do I make the table display all the rows?

Be aware I am a beginner so have no clear understanding of how this should work...

```
try{  
                  String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";//db driver 
                  String myUrl = database;//connect to db
                  Class.forName(myDriver);
                  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, user, password);//authenticating on database
                  PreparedStatement sta = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM customerdb");//prepared statement 

                  ResultSet rst = sta.executeQuery();


         while (rst.next()){


            String cusid = rst.getString("Cus_ID"); //variable to retrieve the customer from the database
            String cusn = rst.getString("Cus_name");
            String cussn = rst.getString("Cus_surname");
            String cusm = rst.getString("Cus_mail");
            String cusaddr = rst.getString("Cus_Address");
            String custel = rst.getString("Cus_telephone");

       if(rst.next()){
          request.setAttribute("ID", cusid);
          request.setAttribute("name", cusn);
          request.setAttribute("surname", cussn);
          request.setAttribute("mail", cusm);
          request.setAttribute("address", cusaddr);
          request.setAttribute("telephone", custel); 


          request.getRequestDispatcher("ListAllCustomer.jsp").forward(request, response); 
       }
```

Comment: Sorry did not put the JSP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your jsp page only show first row is that:
**After fetch the first record, you forward to `ListAllCustomer.jsp` page,then the other rows has no chance to be set**

```
if(rst.next()){
    request.setAttribute("ID", cusid);
    request.setAttribute("name", cusn);
    request.setAttribute("surname", cussn);
    request.setAttribute("mail", cusm);
    request.setAttribute("address", cusaddr);
    request.setAttribute("telephone", custel); 

    //this line make it only shows the first record
    request.getRequestDispatcher("ListAllCustomer.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Also you need to avoid using `rst.next()` when fetch database records,due to each time you call it, it will move to the next record,so you will missing some records to get.

---

For the solution to show all records,you need to redesign your code,my suggestion listed below:

First create a Model call `User` to store the information:

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String mail;
    private String address;
    private String telephone;

    public User(){
    }

    public User(String id, String name, String surname, String mail,
            String address, String telephone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.address = address;
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }
    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }
    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
}
```

Then change your jsp code like below to fetch and store data:

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
while (rst.next()){
    String cusid = rst.getString("Cus_ID"); //variable to retrieve the customer from the database
    String cusn = rst.getString("Cus_name");
    String cussn = rst.getString("Cus_surname");
    String cusm = rst.getString("Cus_mail");
    String cusaddr = rst.getString("Cus_Address");
    String custel = rst.getString("Cus_telephone");

    User user = new User(cusid,cusn,cussn,cusm,cusaddr,custel);
    userList.add(user);
   }

request.setAttribute("userList",userList);
request.getRequestDispatcher("ListAllCustomer.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Finally,you can display records in `ListAllCustomer.jsp` using `JSTL` and `EL Expression` like below:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
  <tr>
   <td>id:</td> <td>${user.id} </td>
   <td>name:</td> <td>${user.name} </td>
   <td>surname:</td> <td>${user.surname} </td>
   <td>mail:</td> <td>${user.mail} </td>
   <td>address:</td> <td>${user.address} </td>
   <td>telephone:</td> <td>${user.telephone} </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah thanks very very much. makes lot of sense now. Only thing is, is there a way to have it on a table instead of a list?

Comment: @VmTech updated my answer,if you think it's okay for you,can you mark my answer as accepted，thank you!